# SQL Server Database storage/performance for 'optional' set of fields

Tags: sql-server, database

(note: contrived example incoming)

I have a business entity called 'Foo':

```
public class Foo
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Which is represented in my DB as a single table like this:

```
FooId   Name
-------------
1       "Bar"
```

I now want to add three `NULL`-table props to the business entity:

```
public class Foo
{
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int? OptionalProp1 { get; set; }
   public int? OptionalProp2 { get; set; }
   public int? OptionalProp3 { get; set; }
}
```

Usually in this scenario, i'd add an extra table, with an FK back to the main 'Foo' table.

However, in my application, i have an indexed view called "FooSearchView", which allows fast reads for a large number of 'Foo' records.

Problem is, with indexed views you cannot have `LEFT OUTER JOIN's`, so i can't achieve the above database modelling.

Any recommendations on how to 'best' store these optional fields? (best = clean database design, optimal performance)

Things that come to mind:

1. Add the extra fields to the table itself (table gets long, but can simply update my indexed view)
2. Use a seperate table, and do a second database call in the app layer. Essentially doing the JOIN at the app/network level.
3. Don't use an indexed view, e.g use a regular index

Any other suggestions or recommendations would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: If each FooID can only have one "OptionalProp1", one "OptionalProp2" and one "OptionalProp3", then storing them in a single table is fine (whatever your FooID base table is, which I guess is whatever table has the name property). The reason you'd use a separate table or separate tables is if a FooID can have multiple OptionalProp1s or if the number of OptionalProps varies (e.g one might have four optional properties). That said, you shouldn't need an indexed view if you have proper indexes on your FooID (or whatever you're joining the tables on, I assume it's FooID).

Comment: @ZLK - yeah, the issue i have is the table gets long, when you end up having all these optional fields. Also, the three fields are part of a single "object", whereas in a row structure there is no apparent grouping. So i guess my problem is more annoyance/OCD than anything else. :)

Comment: @ZLK the indexed view is because we have a 'hot path' where we need to read a set of fields from about 5 different tables. So instead of INNER JOIN'ing everywhere all the time and going back to the PK index to fetch the other fields, we added an indexed view to serve that 'hot path' uniquely.